# C++ libraries in Android

Tags: android

I am writing C++ code using the below given standard libraries for Android environment. As am new to Android, am not sure whether all these files are supported in Android NDK. I downloaded the latest NDK from dev site.

Are they supported?

If not, is there a way to work around that?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, they are supported, except `stdafx.h`.

Answer (score 0):

"stdafx.h" is a Windows-only header file. It's not going to work.

The rest are all standard, cross platform libraries that will work just fine.

Comment: When i try to use #include <string> , Eclipse gives an error - fatal error: string: No such file or directory. Why's that?

Comment: It defaults to C, which doesn't have <string>. You should either use <string.h>, or make sure you're building with C++.